# Find the latest rating for each category for each customer

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

The data in the rating table looks like this:

| StudentID | Rating | ScoreType | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | RAPID | 2023-01-01 |
| 1 | 15 | RAPID | 2023-01-10 |
| 1 | 20 | RAPID | 2023-02-15 |
| 1 | 25 | RAPID | 2023-02-20 |
| 1 | 25 | BLITZ | 2023-03-01 |
| 1 | 33 | BLITZ | 2023-03-20 |
| 2 | 17 | RAPID | 2023-01-15 |
| 2 | 19 | BLITZ | 2023-02-06 |

What I am trying to build is like this:

| StudentID | RAPID_Rating | RAPID_Games | BLITZ_Rating | BLITZ_Games | Total Games |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 | 4 | 33 | 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 17 | 1 | 19 | 1 | 2 |

The data should be one row for each student

Column definitions of the expected output:

RAPID_Rating : Latest rating value based on date where ScoreType = 'RAPID'

RAPID_Games: Total number of RAPID games played by each student

BLITZ_Rating: Latest rating value based on date where ScoreType = 'BLITZ'

BLITZ_Games: Total number of BLIRZ games played by each student

Total Games: Total games played by each student

The SQL Code that I have tried:

```
select
    coalesce(a.StudentID,b.StudentID) as StudentID,
    a.rating as RAPID_Rating,
    RAPID_Games,
    b.rating as BLITZ_Rating,
    BLITZ_Games,
    RAPID_Games + BLITZ_Games as Total_Games
    
from 
(select 
    StudentID, 
    ScoreType,
    rating,
    count(rating) over(partition by StudentID,ScoreType) as RAPID_Games,
    row_number() over(partition by StudentID,ScoreType order by date desc) as RNUM
from rating 
    where ScoreType ='RAPID'
) a join (
    select 
    StudentID, 
    ScoreType,
    rating,
    count(rating) over(partition by StudentID,ScoreType) as BLITZ_Games,
    row_number() over(partition by StudentID,ScoreType order by date desc) as RNUM
from rating 
    where ScoreType ='BLITZ'
) b on a.StudentID = b.StudentID 
where a.RNUM = 1 and b.RNUM = 1
```

I have to do this calculation for another 2 categories then that will add up another 2 sub queries. Is there anyway to optimize this SQL code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` along with conditional aggregation here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID, ScoreType ORDER BY Date DESC) rn
    FROM rating
)

SELECT
    StudentID,
    MAX(Rating) FILTER (WHERE ScoreType = 'RAPID' AND rn = 1) AS RAPID_Rating,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE ScoreType = 'RAPID') AS RAPID_Games,
    MAX(Rating) FILTER (WHERE ScoreType = 'BLITZ' AND rn = 1) AS BLITZ_Rating,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE ScoreType = 'BLITZ') AS BLITZ_Games,
    COUNT(*) AS "Total Games"
FROM cte
GROUP BY StudentID
ORDER BY StudentID;
```